# I am getting an Error saying "no operator << matches these operands" and I am not sure why this is appearing

Tags: c++

In the code, I am trying to have eight values inputted by the user and then have those values added together, added together, and then added by three, and finally have the total amount of miles divided by eight. However, when I went to run this code I got an error saying no operator << matches these operands.

Here is the code in question, I apologize for any bad formatting I'm a new user to this website.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int hourswalked, hourswalkedD2, hourswalkedD3, hourswalkedD4, hourswalkedD5, 
        hourswalkedD6, hourswalkedD7,hourswalkedD8;

    int total_hours = hourswalked + hourswalkedD2 + hourswalkedD3 + hourswalkedD4 + hourswalkedD5 + hourswalkedD6 + hourswalkedD7 + hourswalkedD8;
    int total_miles = total_hours * 3;
    int avg_miles = total_miles / 8;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the number of hours you have walked each day of your hike" << endl;

    cin >> hourswalked >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD2 >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD3 >> endl; 
    cin >> hourswalkedD4 >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD5 >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD6 >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD7 >> endl;
    cin >> hourswalkedD8 >> endl;

    cout << "You walked for " << total_hours << " hours." << endl;

    cout << "You walked for " << total_miles << " miles." << endl; 

    cout << "On average you walked " << avg_miles << " miles." << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: you don't need `>> endl` when using `cin`.

Comment: Are you sure the error was about `<<` and not `>>`?

Comment: Also, you must do the calculations *after* you have assigned values to the eight inputs.

Comment: Off topic, but you should read up on loops and [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s.

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about using those variables before giving them a value. Make sure your warning level is turned up.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to get an error for using the last ">>" operator in cin.

You don't have to use "`>> endl`" while you're taking input. It's only required while you want to print a new line, not when you're taking input.

Just remove all the "`>> endl`" while taking input, you're good to go.

Code Sample:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int hourswalked, hourswalkedD2, hourswalkedD3, hourswalkedD4, hourswalkedD5,
        hourswalkedD6, hourswalkedD7,hourswalkedD8;

    int total_hours = hourswalked + hourswalkedD2 + hourswalkedD3 + hourswalkedD4 + hourswalkedD5 + hourswalkedD6 + hourswalkedD7 + hourswalkedD8;
    int total_miles = total_hours * 3;
    int avg_miles = total_miles / 8;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the number of hours you have walked each day of your hike" << endl;

    cin >> hourswalked;
    cin >> hourswalkedD2;
    cin >> hourswalkedD3;
    cin >> hourswalkedD4;
    cin >> hourswalkedD5;
    cin >> hourswalkedD6;
    cin >> hourswalkedD7;
    cin >> hourswalkedD8;

    cout << "You walked for " << total_hours << " hours." << endl;

    cout << "You walked for " << total_miles << " miles." << endl;

    cout << "On average you walked " << avg_miles << " miles." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, you don't need endl. Also use an array of 8 to store your hours.

```
int main()
{
    int hourswalked   = 0,
        hourswalkedD2 = 0,
        hourswalkedD3 = 0,
        hourswalkedD4 = 0,
        hourswalkedD5 = 0,
        hourswalkedD6 = 0,
        hourswalkedD7 = 0,
        hourswalkedD8 = 0;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the number of hours you have walked each day of your hike" << endl;

    cin >> hourswalked
        >> hourswalkedD2
        >> hourswalkedD3
        >> hourswalkedD4
        >> hourswalkedD5
        >> hourswalkedD6
        >> hourswalkedD7
        >> hourswalkedD8;

    int total_hours = hourswalked + hourswalkedD2 + hourswalkedD3 + 
    hourswalkedD4 + hourswalkedD5 + hourswalkedD6 + hourswalkedD7 + 
    hourswalkedD8;

    int total_miles = total_hours * 3;
    int avg_miles = total_miles / 8;

    cout << "You walked for " << total_hours << " hours." << endl
         << "You walked for " << total_miles << " miles." << endl
         << "On average you walked " << avg_miles << " miles." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This removed the operand error but now all the other operations do not work because all the variables are now just set to 0 and when I run the code the the it outputs 0 for total hours total miles and average  miles

Comment: I updated it, it's because you have to do the calculations after the user gives you the values.

Comment: OOooooooh Okay I didn't know that the order of the code mattered that much in C++ because I remember in python you could put your variables in the beginning and write the rest of the code as you want, along with HTML where you can segment stuff in the head and body. I guess old habits die hard lol

Comment: @tgol, [Python is the same](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MboW6Kc15), it will execute the lines in order and use the value in the variable at the time of the line being executed.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` takes in user input, you can remember this by the `>>` operator looks like it is funnelling the data into the variable. So when you put the `std::endl` you are "funnelling" the data to `std::cin` from the variable, but that is not what `std::endl` is for. Your solution is below:

```
std::cin >> hoursWalked;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int hourswalked, hourswalkedD2, hourswalkedD3, hourswalkedD4, hourswalkedD5, 
    hourswalkedD6, hourswalkedD7,hourswalkedD8;


cout << endl << "Please enter the number of hours you have walked each day of your hike" << endl;

cin >> hourswalked;
cin >> hourswalkedD2;
cin >> hourswalkedD3; 
cin >> hourswalkedD4;
cin >> hourswalkedD5;
cin >> hourswalkedD6;
cin >> hourswalkedD7;
cin >> hourswalkedD8;


int total_hours = hourswalked + hourswalkedD2 + hourswalkedD3 + hourswalkedD4 + hourswalkedD5 + hourswalkedD6 + hourswalkedD7 + hourswalkedD8;
int total_miles = total_hours * 3;
int avg_miles = total_miles / 8;

cout << "You walked for " << total_hours << " hours." << endl;

cout << "You walked for " << total_miles << " miles." << endl; 

cout << "On average you walked " << avg_miles << " miles." << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.